# Angularjs unable to read params from a URLencoded URL using $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have configured the routes like this in my app :

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {action: 'account_landing_page'})
    .when('/:resource/:id/:extrajson', {action: 'open_resource'})
    .when('/:resource/:id', {action: 'open_resource'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
```

I want to be able to perform different operation if the url contains `:extrajson`. So I have this URL :
`xyz/dashboard/1/%7B%22screen_shot_mode%22%3A%20%22on%22%7D`

When this URL loads it loses all the urlencoded extra parameters and becomes :
`xyz/#/dashboard/1`

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong over here?
Can somebody explain me why is it happening?

Comment: you should pass that content as search param, i don't think browsers support that as valid paths

Comment: Can you tell me why the params are getting lost?

Comment: like i said in my previous comment, my guess is the string you are passed is not  a valid url path, hence they are being stript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some snippets of code that might help you understand.

```
  when('/search/:someid', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/qviewplaceholder.html',
    controller: 'Myctrl as somectrl'
  }).
```

Notice the ":someid" part.  Down in the controller will look this.

```
app.controller('Myctrl', ['$routeParams',function($routeParams) {
this.somedata = $routeParams.someid;
/*controller logic that uses $routeParams.someid for it's logic*/
}]);
```

You now have a template [partials/qviewplaceholder.html] and a variable passed into it via $routeParams.  The $routeParams variable is usually some id that can be used to point to some object. Then display the data accordingly.  Also, here is a video demonstrating the use of $routeparams. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziUelciLL5Q

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are meant to be part of the URL path. So it would match `/:resource/:id/:extrajson` to `/foo/bar/baz`, where $routeParams gets parsed into:

```
{
  "resource": "foo",
  "id": "bar",
  "extrajson": "baz"
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: Can you tell me why the params are getting lost?